# Deselecting a radio button if it is already selected

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have a [scheduling app](http://vols.herokuapp.com) that I am transitioning over to html from svg. The behavior that I am trying to replicate is a list of icons only one of which can be selected. If a selected icon is clicked, it unselects leaving none selected.

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wholcomb/yjN4t/7/) where I am trying to set up the appropriate layout. For HTML I have:

```
<ul class="hour open" hour="17">
  <li class="shift">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="shift[1]"/>
      <img class="icon" src="http://dhappy.org/.../image/icon/hand/"/>
    </label>
  </li>
  ⋮
```

This handles the selection of a single entry, but I am still having issues unselecting an item if it is clicked when selected. The code I have is:

```
$('label').click( function( event ) {
  if( $(this).children( 'input' ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
     $(this).children( 'input' ).prop( { checked: false } )
  }
} )
```

This seems to be getting called twice for each click. Once with `checked` being `false` and then with `true`. The end effect is the buttons are unselectable. What should I change?

The answers don't seem to be addressing my central question which is I want a radio button to be unselected if it is selected when it is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your fiddle, you can solve this problem by using 
[**`event.preventDefault()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('label').click( function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault(); //Added
  if( $(this).children( 'input' ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
     $(this).children( 'input' ).prop( { checked: false } )
  }
});
```

**Updates:** Based on your comments

```
$('label').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var ele = $(this).find('input');
        if (!ele.prop('disabled') && !ele.prop('checked'))   
                 $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
        else 
            $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false);    
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjN4t/11/)

Comment: The radio buttons are not selectable. I would like to be able to select them and then when I click on a selected one have none selected for that group.

Comment: @Will I have change the approach, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yjN4t/10/ and share your thoughts.

Comment: @Will I missed about `disabled` attribute. here is a corrected fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yjN4t/11/

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop propagation of the click event on radio which gets trigegred when you clcik the label

```
 $(':radio').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation()        
 })
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yjN4t/9/)**</kbd>

Comment: The behavior I am trying to achieve is to be able to click a selected item and have it unselect.

Comment: seems to do that for the ones that aren't disabled...in FF anyway